# filter data on jsonb with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

imagine you have website where people post their ads. So, each ad has some selected properties, for example cars has different engine types, gears, colors and etc. Those properties user selects before submiting a listing. 
I store selected properties in a jsonb format in listings table, look at the data column:

[image: link to image].

So, each listing contains data like this:

```
{
   "properties":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "value_id":"1"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "value_id":"5"
      },
      {
         "id":"3",
         "value_id":"9"
      },
      {
         "id":"4",
         "value":"2.0"
      },
      {
         "id":"7",
         "value":"2017"
      },
      {
         "id":"6",
         "value":"180.000"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, the question is:

1) How to filter listings by those id's and value's which are in json? For example, show listings where id = 2 and it's value = 5 AND id = 3 and it's value = 9 and so on. I dont need **OR**, i need **AND**. So, filter data by multiple id's and value's.

2) First point + ability to compare id's and value's (greater or lower than).

Comment: From example it looks like you're storing in jsonb what should be a separate table.

Comment: @Justinas Marozas, in a separate table i have translations and other meta data for those properties. That's because website has several languages. And I do JOIN on those value's and id's to other table.

Comment: But why are you using jsonb for this data that has a regular structure? Why not a separate three column table (complete with FKs)? Or even an array of jsonb like `array['{"id":"1","value_id":"1"}'::jsonb, '{"id":"2","value_id":"5"}', ...]`?

Answer (score 0):

answering first point, it's probably the first time when I find use for `jsonb[]`:

```
t=# with c(a,j) as (values(18,'{
   "properties":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "value_id":"1"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "value_id":"5"
      },
      {
         "id":"3",
         "value_id":"9"
      },
      {
         "id":"4",
         "value":"2.0"
      },
      {
         "id":"7",
         "value":"2017"
      },
      {
         "id":"6",
         "value":"180.000"
      }
   ]
}'::jsonb), (19,'{"properties":[{"id": "1", "value_id": "1"}]}'))
, m as (select a, array_agg(jb.value)::jsonb[] ar from c, jsonb_array_elements(j->'properties') jb group by a)
select a 
from m 
where '{"id": "1", "value_id": "1"}'::jsonb = any(ar) 
  and '{"id": "3", "value_id": "9"}'::jsonb = any(ar);
 a
----
 18
(1 row)
```

and for the second requirement - it won't be that short, as you need to compare (and thus parse json):

```
t=# with c(a,j) as (values(18,'{
   "properties":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "value_id":"1"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "value_id":"5"
      },
      {
         "id":"3",
         "value_id":"9"
      },
      {
         "id":"4",
         "value":"2.0"
      },
      {
         "id":"7",
         "value":"2017"
      },
      {
         "id":"6",
         "value":"180.000"
      }
   ]
}'::jsonb), (19,'{"properties":[{"id": "1", "value_id": "1"}]}'))
, m as (select a, jb.value->>'id' id,jb.value->>'value_id' value_id from c, jsonb_array_elements(j->'properties') jb)
, n as (select m.*, count(1) over (partition by m.a)
from m
join c on c.a = m.a and ((id::int >= 1 and value_id::int <2) or (id::int >2 and value_id::int <= 9)))
select distinct a from n
where count > 1;
 a
----
 18
(1 row)
```

with basic idea to use `OR` to get possible rows and then check if ALL of `OR` conditions were met

Comment: Yeah, that's really not a short query. After my research I think I will agree with other comments above, it's better to create a separate table for values and keys and that's it. More easier - more better.

Comment: obviously creating the table, instead of keeping its data in jsonb is better idea :) I was answering your question - how you can QUERY it, not solve the normalization problem